# Export Object List content in a Text file in a tabular order using C#

Tags: c#, text-files, export-to-text

i have an object list and i Would like to export it in a text file.
I would like that the properties name are the column header.

I 've done this

```
public static void Write(IList<ValidationResultAttribute> dt, string filePath)
        {
            int i = 0;
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);

            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ValidationResultAttribute).GetProperties();
            // write columns header
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                sw.Write(property.Name + "  ");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();


            // write value
            foreach (ValidationResultAttribute res in dt)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] prop = typeof(ValidationResultAttribute).GetProperties();

                foreach (PropertyInfo property in prop)
                {
                    sw.Write(property.GetValue(res, null) + "  ");
                }
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

but I've this output

```
PresentationName    SlideName   ShapeName   RunIndexs   Attribute   Rule        Fail    Pass  
pptTest.pptx        Slide1      Rectangle 3 FontSize    Value       22          1       0  
pptTest.pptx        Slide2      TextBox 3   FontSize    Between     20and 72    1       0
```

there is a way to format the output txt file (value under the column)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.format to get the desired result. Works also with `sw.Write(format, args)`

```
sw.Write("[{0,-20}|{1,10}]", "UnitPrice", 3.4457M);
```

will write

```
[UnitPrice           |    3,4457]
```

A negative value behind the format specifier mean left align a positiv value means right align.

There is one pitfall, This methods will not truncate your data, so

```
    sw.Write("[{0,-20}|{1,10}]", "ThisStringIsLongerThanExpected", 3.4457M);
```

will result in

```
[ThisStringIsLongerThanExpected|    3,4457]
```

So choose the values large enough or trim your strings to fit.

In your case you could calculate the length based on which is longer the properties name or it's value.

```
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ValidationResultAttribute).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            values.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(res, null);
        }

        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            var length = Math.Max(value.Key.Length, value.Value.ToString().Length);
            var format = "{0,-" + length.ToString() + "} ";
            sw.Write(format, value.Key);
        }
        sw.WriteLine();

        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            var length = Math.Max(value.Key.Length, value.Value.ToString().Length);
            var format = "{0,-" + length.ToString() + "} ";
            sw.Write(format, value.Value);
        }
        sw.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following code changes to create tab delimited file. This file is easy to parse and easy to read.

1. `sw.Write(property.Name + "  ");` change this to `sw.Write(property.Name + "\t");`
2. `sw.Write(property.GetValue(res, null) + "  ");` change this to `sw.Write(property.GetValue(res, null) + "\t");`